# How to add entry (pointing to Activity) to "Home Screen -> Menu -> Add-> Shortcuts"?

Tags: android

I'm writing program for Android (SDK 1.5). I would like to know how to add/register one of my program activities in "Home Screen -> Menu -> Add-> Shortcuts" (or on Hero "Home Screen -> Menu -> Add to Home-> Shortcut") so that user will be able to add it to his home screen. Is there an Intent Filter or any other way to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is actually covered in the [API Samples (App/"Launcher Shortcuts")](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LauncherShortcuts.html). Also check out the ApiDemos manifest, which provides a pretty good explanation (look for the LauncherShortcuts part).

Basically, your provide an intent filter in your manifest containing

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
```

In the activity you defined as the receiver, you check if the calling intent is a **ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT** intent, and if so create a returning intent with some extras (check out  the setupShortcut function in the link I provided).
You could also check out the source code for [Connectbot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) which does this pretty well. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

See [`Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT).