# JQuery Mobile Add the Home Screen Options?

Tags: html, css, mobile, cross-browser, jquery-mobile

I know that there is no way of auto adding the JQuery Mobile App to the Home Screen.

I've read that the best way is to detect if the app is in full screen and if not give instructions. How would I do this?

What are the cross browser options available and are there any tutorials / samples anywhere?

Can anyone put some light on this please?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? I know it's possible for Android as I have seen it somewhere recently. Links below for Android don't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not 'Auto Add' as webapp to your home screen, the only option is thing: http://www.tuaw.com/2008/12/19/iphone-101-add-mobile-websites-to-home-screen/

Note: Auto Adding a webapp to your homescreen would be a really bad thing, just think any webpage you went to could auto add itself to your iphone. NO THANKS!!!

UPDATE:

I think this is what you're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/
I have made a Feature Request (under new widgets) for this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Feature-Requests

Related Links:

- [Javascript for "Add to Home Screen" on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141979/javascript-for-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone)
- [how to Add a Button on the home screen in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489274/how-to-add-a-button-on-the-home-screen-in-android)
- [How to add entry (pointing to Activity) to "Home Screen -> Menu -> Add-> Shortcuts"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451350/how-to-add-entry-pointing-to-activity-to-home-screen-menu-add-shortcut)
- [BlackBerry - How to add content to the Home Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330940/blackberry-how-to-add-content-to-the-home-screen)
- [Install home screen widgets progrommaticly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084862/install-home-screen-widgets-progrommaticly)

Maybe Notification Popup?
 - [How to show the "add to home screen" popup window and notifications like the buildin home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360608/how-to-show-the-add-to-home-screen-popup-window-and-notifications-like-the-buil)
 - [Is there a JQuery plugin for the iPhone that will notify the user to "Bookmark" their app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375174/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-for-the-iphone-that-will-notify-the-user-to-bookmark-t)

Comment: I userstand that and agree ... but I'd like something where the user gets instructions and told that he can go full screen by doing whatever is needed...etc..

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/ link from here leads to 404:(

Answer (score 2):

Here's another script targeted at iOS browsers that seems similar to mobile-bookmark-bubble:
http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

Some work has been done here to add support for Android:
http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/issues/detail?id=12 
http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/issues/detail?id=17