# Jquerymobile HTML5 Iphone App Add to Home screen

Tags: iphone, html, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a Mobile App with JQM and JSP I'm using Bookmark bubble to do this, but I just want to ensure I understand what is happening behind the scenes here.

Is the static HTML generated by my JSP saved locally on the iPhone? 
Does clicking on the APP always get fresh info from my online server or does it cache?

I'm assuming it still uses Safari to render? And just hides the toolbar etc?

If instead of hosting this online, I packaged it as an Apple App and it went on App store,
would the device still use safari to render it?

Thanks!

Comment: The only way to "package" the website you've created into an app would be to use something like PhoneGap. It wouldn't be viewed in Safari, but it would still use the same browser technology (webkit) on the inside though.

Comment: Hi Todd, thanks for your words. Is it typical for ppl to create paid apps using JQM -> PhoneGap, as long as the app is fairly simplistic I don't see any loss from using objective-c etc?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162070/jquery-mobile-add-the-home-screen-options

Comment: Well, if it's simplistic, then with PhoneGap you could have the same app running on iOS, Android, Blackberry, etc.. without major changes to the HTML and javascript code. But obj-c will only run on iOS. There are a number of paid apps written in PhoneGap. You can certainly write your own "wrapper" in obj-c around an HTML5 site, but why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is at: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

It's possible to cache the page(s) locally.