# Create icon on device home screen for BlackBerry

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a web-based mobile app written in jQuery Mobile, but would like to know if there's a way to add an icon to my BlackBerry home screen that points to the web location.  Is there a way to do this programmatically using jQuery Mobile or PhoneGap?  Since it's written in jQuery Mobile, would I even be able to use PhoneGap?  I can't find anything on this on the web.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162070/jquery-mobile-add-the-home-screen-options

Answer (score 1):

Joshua Rose, after doing some research myself you need to develop a simple app in Java whose sole goal when clicked is open the browser and go to the URL you have designated, here is an article: - [How to Invoke the Browser](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800440/How_To_-_Invoke_the_browser.html?nodeid=1487366&vernum=0).

Answer (score 0):

Currently your app is web based. For making it a true app you need to port the application as a native application using jQuery mobile and phone gap. After that ist really simple to add an icon :)